# Nextcord Slash Commands

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I've heard that nextcord has now slash commands! That's great, and this is why I want to add them in my bot. I've already watched YouTube tutorials, but, for some reason, it doesn't work. This is my main.py file

```py
from IMPORTANT.keep_alive import keep_alive
import os

try:
    from nextcord.ext import commands
    from nextcord import Interaction
    import nextcord
    
except ImportError:
    os.system("pip install -U nextcord")
    from nextcord.ext import commands
    from nextcord import Interaction
    import nextcord

intents = nextcord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="+", intents=intents)
bot.remove_command("help")
server = 896366068417830933

for file in os.listdir("./cogs/commands"):
    if file.endswith(".py"): 
        name = file[:-3]
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.commands.{name}") 

for file in os.listdir("./cogs/events"):
    if file.endswith(".py"): 
        name = file[:-3]
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.events.{name}") 
    
# slash command test
@bot.slash_command(name="test", description="commande de test", guild_ids=[server])
async def test(interaction: Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("les slashs commands fonctionnent")

keep_alive()
bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

EDIT: Idk if it changes something but I use repl.it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it works for me.
Maybe this will fix it

1. if you are using the event "`on_interaction`"

   ```
   if interaction.type == InteractionType.application_command:
   await self.client.process_application_commands(interaction)
   ```
2. reinvite the bot with the following permission

   `applications.commands`

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be because, by looking at your code you made the command name `"commande de test"` and slash commands don't work that way unless you use what is called sub-commands, so I would say just call the command `test` or something.

Comment: "command de test" is the description.

Comment: oh apologies I didn't read it wrong. Can you possibly say what the error is because saying "it doesn't work" can't help much since we don't know the exact problem but it's possibly because you didn't invite the bot with the `applications.commands` scope.

Comment: The problem is that even with all permissions, the bbot isn't able to use them.

Comment: can you possibly send the full error then? sorry i haven't been on stack much, school problems lol

Comment: it's not even sending an error

Answer (score 0):

1. You only say "doesn't work" - this is very broad of an issue.
2. Have you authorised your bot with the OAuth2 `applications.commands` (Invite link, it's like the `bot` scope). Any users will also need to reauth - no need to kick the bot, just reuse the link